# When i click on submit button in client no action went to the node JS?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am new to Node JS and stucked in http GET and POST method. I can't call back from node JS using submit button.

**server.js**

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, resp) {
  session = req.session;
  if (session.uniqueID != 'admin') {
    resp.send('Unauthorized acess');
  }
  resp.sendFile('/.html', {
    root: __dirname
  });
});


app.post('/admin', function(req, resp) {
  resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  e.preventDefult();
  console.log('admin');

});
```

**home.html**

```
<body>
  <div class="loginBox">
    <img src="user.png" class="user">
    <h2>Docker</h2>
    <form id="tableForm">
      <select>
        <optgroup label="Select docker commands here">
          <option name="" value="0" />
          <option name="table1" value="1">docker start</option>
          <option name="table2" value="2">docker build</option>
          <option name="table3" value="3">docker run</option>
          <option name="table3" value="3">docker pull</option>
          <option name="table3" value="3">docker stop</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select><br>
      <input type="button" value="submit" /></a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I select home page dropdown list on click submit button I want return to the admin post method.

Is any one have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

In server file you don't have `e.preventDefult();`. So just log your message and add rest of your codes. Also `/.html` is not a correct file you used.

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, resp) {
  session = req.session;
  if (session.uniqueID != 'admin') {
    resp.send('Unauthorized acess');
  }
  resp.sendFile('/.html', {
    root: __dirname
  });
});


app.post('/admin', function(req, resp) {
  console.log('admin');
});
```

And in html file add `action="/admin" method="POST"` to your form, which after submitting, request send to server.

```
<body>
  <div class="loginBox">
    <img src="user.png" class="user">
    <h2>Docker</h2>
    <form action="/admin" method="POST" id="tableForm">
      <select>
        <optgroup label="Select docker commands here">
          <option name="" value="0" />
          <option name="table1" value="1">docker start</option>
          <option name="table2" value="2">docker build</option>
          <option name="table3" value="3">docker run</option>
          <option name="table3" value="3">docker pull</option>
          <option name="table3" value="3">docker stop</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select><br>
      <input type="button" value="submit" /></a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer have no description. You just write the change in html. also OP's code have some issues in server side. and I do not DV your answer @SanjaySinghBhandari

Comment: @Saeed  it's working in a single button, but it won't work in a dropdown list have any idea?

Comment: You have to use a `submit` button to send the request to server. Provide your code in a codepen or plunker to help @maniR